# Spawn GameObjects accroding to player movement- Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, spawn, gameobject, procedural-generation

I am making a game arcade style where there is a plane and I want prefabs which are walls to get spawned or instantiated according to the player movement, as of now there is a code that helps in getting the walls generated in one direction, The main motive is to spawn these prefabs in all 4 directions with respect to the rotation.

```
 void Update()
{
   
    float distanceTowards= Vector3.Distance(Player.gameObject.transform.position, SpawnPosition);

    if (distanceTowards < 20)
    {
        SpawnWalls();
    }

}
void SpawnWalls()
{
    SpawnPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, SpawnPosition.z + 10);
    Instantiate(Walls, SpawnPosition,Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Really get stuck with this, seeking support.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this description. I don't know, if you want a square of wall following you, or walls only on sides, what is spawn point and how many spawn point exist, etc. Could you provide some video of what you already got and/or image what you expect to happen?

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJA7B7RJWNM&ab_channel=CodingCafe) followed this tutorial for the making of the above code, The requirement is that there are already placed walls in 4 sides of the player. as the player moves or comes near these walls, 
 the same prefab should be generated at the back of the respective walls, at a certain distance. Hope the motive is clear.

Answer (score 0):

From you question and the link in comments, what I understand is you want to spawn a wall in the direction the player is facing when the player reaches the existing wall.

Your code should look like this

```
    void Update()
    {
       
        float distanceTowards= Vector3.Distance(Player.gameObject.transform.position, SpawnPosition);
    
        if (distanceTowards < 20 && notspawned)
        {
            SpawnWalls();
        }
        if(distanceTowards>20)
        {

            notspawned=true;
        }
    
    }
    void SpawnWalls()
    {
        Instantiate(Walls, Player.gameObject.transform.forward*spawndistance,Quaternion.identity);
notspawned=false;
    }
```

spawndistance is how far you want the object to be spawned.
notspawned is bool that you have to set to true at first.

Comment: Thank you for this, this partially does the job, now it seems like If the distance is less than the distance, it spawns indefinitely around, Is it possible to just spawn just one at every point?

Comment: You can add a Boolean to check if the object is spawned. I have updated to code with your requirement. If you need one on one mentoring then you can book a paid session with me here. https://vionixstudio.com/tutoring-service/